# conditionally selecting two numeric row values in R

Tags: r, subset

I'm trying to subset a data set to remove all values before the 7th month of the year 2011. I have Years and Months in different columns.

What I am doing I know is logically wrong(also getting a wrong output), but can't seem to figure out the right way to do this:

```
state_in2_check <-  subset(state_in2, Month > 6 &  Year > 2011)
```

Comment: please share sample data and the output you are getting, and the desired output

Comment: Try `state_in2_check <-  subset(state_in2, state_in2$Month > 6 &  state_in2$Year > 2011)`. You need to refer to the columns of `state_in2` explicitly.

Comment: @MauritsEvers - no you don't. `subset(mtcars, mpg > 18 & cyl == 4)`

Comment: @thelatemail You're right, I never realised that. My mistake. Ignore my comment.

Comment: `subset(state_in2, (Month > 6 & Year == 2011) | Year >= 2012 )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@thelatemail has given you a workable solution in the comments. Your problem is that You're asking R to match two logical checks separately, but each of those checks is dependant on the other. You won't, for example, get any "January" dates (because you're only accepting months greater than 6), even though "Jan-2013" would be fine. @thelatemail's solution separates the checks, such that months lower than 6 will be accepted, as long as they're in years greater than 2011.

Another way would be to convert to date at the same time as subsetting, this way the process is a little more logical:

```
Month <- 7
Year <- 2011
as.Date( paste( Year, Month, 15, sep = "-" ) )
[1] "2011-07-15"
```

You can use that simple conversion to subset in a more (in my opinion) logical way:

```
state_in2_check <- subset(state_in2, 
                           as.Date( paste( Year, Month, 15, sep = "-" ) ) > 
                               as.Date( "2011-06-15" )
)
```

Note I've made the day of the month the same in both date conversions, which will mean they're compared only according to month/year.

Comment: I understand now ! Cheers